# Multiple SET in single UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, merge, sql-update

I'm working on SQL Server, Oracle, DB2 Database.

Currently, I'm performing the below 2 update statement to update one table.

Update 1:

```
UPDATE  TABLE1
SET COL1=TABLE2.ATTRIBUTE1,
    COL2=TABLE2.ATTRIBUTE2,
    COL3=TABLE2.ATTRIBUTE3
FROM TABLE1
     INNER JOIN TABLE2
     ON COL1=TABLE2.PID1
     AND COL2=TABLE2.PID2
WHERE ROWNUM<10
```

Update 2:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET COL1=’123-4567890-1’,
    COL2=’0000000000’,
    COL3=’CONSTANT FULL NAME’
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE COL1=TABLE2.PID1)
```

Update 1, helps to updates the TABLE1  if the values match with Table2 and 
Update 2, helps to update the TABLE1  if the values, not match with Table2

Is there any other way to convert two update statement into single UPDATE statement?

NOTE: We can use MERGE also, but MERGE will update if the data matched and will insert if the data not matched.

Comment: You should really decide what database you are working on.  The data has to be stored *somewhere*.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff for the reply. I have to implement this update in ORACLE, SQL SERVER, DB2 LUW, AS400, ZOS.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  the above update statement is from SQL SERVER,I am having different kind of statement in different database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have one update, you can use two LEFT JOINs, one for each table join condition. And then, in SET part, you use CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END  checking if the PK from related joins IS NULL.

Something like below

```
UPDATE  TABLE1
SET COL1=CASE 
     WHEN T1.PID1 IS NOT NULL THEN T1.ATTRIBUTE1 
     WHEN T2.PID1 IS NULL THEN ’123-4567890-1’
     ELSE COL1
    END,

    etc.

FROM TABLE1
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T1 ON COL1=T1.PID1 AND COL2=T1.PID2 AND ROWNUM < 10
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON CEDULA=T2.PID1

WHERE T2.PID1 IS NULL OR T1.PID1 IS NOT NULL
```

However, having one UPDATE statement doesn't mean it will be faster - check the query plan and actual performance.

Comment: Thank you Sir for the reply, I will check this query.

Comment: @VivekHarry, np. Keep in mind that you may need to change the order of WHEN ... THEN ... statements, depending on priority (because you have different sets of join conditions, you may have conflicts - depends on your data).

Comment: Understand Sir. Thanks again.

Comment: This query works fine, in 2nd Left Join statement, ON should come instead of WHERE . Thank you so much Anton. I really Appreciate your help.

Comment: @VivekHarry, type is fixed )

Comment: Wonderful Anton.